# How to combine count group by with where to get result from 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to  find the `full_name`, `email_id`, `phone number` and `referral code` of all the tenants who have referred more than once. There are 2 table and I am trying to get the data which has referred more than twice.  My code don't have error sign but on running the query its giving me error

> An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a
>   subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column
>   being aggregated is an outer reference.

```
select dbo.Profiles.first_name + ' ' + dbo.Profiles.last_name as full_name,dbo.Profiles.email, dbo.Profiles.phone ,dbo.Profiles.referral_code  from dbo.Profiles 
where profile_id = (select referrer_id from dbo.Referrals where COUNT(referrer_id)>2 group by dbo.Referrals.referrer_id)
```

Answer (score 2):

in subselect you should use having for filter aggregated  values

```
  select 
      dbo.Profiles.first_name + ' ' + dbo.Profiles.last_name as full_name
      ,dbo.Profiles.email
      , dbo.Profiles.phone
      ,dbo.Profiles.referral_code  
  from dbo.Profiles 
  where profile_id = ( 
        select referrer_id 
        from dbo.Referrals 
        group by dbo.Referrals.referrer_id
         HAVING COUNT(referrer_id)>2 
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select dbo.Profiles.first_name + ' ' + dbo.Profiles.last_name as 
full_name,dbo.Profiles.email, dbo.Profiles.phone ,dbo.Profiles.referral_code  
from dbo.Profiles 
where profile_id = 
(select referrer_id from dbo.Referrals 
  group by dbo.Referrals.referrer_id
  having COUNT(READ_BELOW)>2
)
```

- I am assuming referrer_id is a different name for profile_id.
- Replace READ_BELOW with whatever the unique key field for  dbo.Referrals

Comment: Questions: 
- Does the referrals table have profile_id ?
- For two rows in referrals by the same person, does it have the same value of referrer_id or different?
- What is the primary key for dbo_referrals ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT referrer_id, COUNT(*) AS 'Count_'
INTO  #RefCount
FROM dbo.Referrals
GROUP BY referrer_id

SELECT dbo.Profiles.first_name + ' ' + dbo.Profiles.last_name AS 'Full_Name', 
dbo.Profiles.email, dbo.Profiles.phone ,dbo.Profiles.referral_code  
FROM dbo.Profiles, #RefCount RC 
WHERE dbo.Profiles.profile_id = RC.referrer_id
AND RC.Count_ > 2
```